# How to display multi-line text in Visio Shape Data?

Tags: model, process, mapping, visio, journey

I'm looking for a way to fuse Customer Journey Mapping with Process Modeling to solve the problem of journey conditionality.  Visio is so very close to being able to solve this problem, but...

```
 1. You cannot nicely display multi-line text in Shape Data
 2. Screen Tip is clumsy to use
 3. Comments is cluttered and disconnected form a shape metadata
```

If Microsoft simply added a Rich Text multi-line option to Shape Data this would be a rock solid solution.

Ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Multi-line text can be done. Just insert a **\n** into the shapedata, like this:

This is text on\n2 lines